# From where does it look like a "frog" to you?

Tags: word-usage, speech

Our teacher (she teaches psychology), was telling us about the ink-blot test (used to tell a person's personality). She was **asking a girl (who volunteered) a few questions**.  She said that **"it looked like a frog to her**". So our teacher asked:

> **From where** does it look like a frog to you? (She's asking exactly what part of that ink-blot appears to her as a frog)

Is the use of **"from where"** natural or should it be **"where does it look like a frog to you"?**

Comment: As they say, there are many ways to skin a cat. Both versions are acceptable and there are other ways of asking a similar question e.g. "In what way does it look...?" and "What makes it look like...?"

Comment: If the girl said that the entire ink blot looked like a frog, it doesn't make sense to interpret the teacher's "from where" question as meaning "Which part of the ink blot looks to you like a frog?" Rather, the teacher may have had in mind something like "From what perspective or in what orientation does the ink blot look like a frog?" The teacher might have asked that question more succinctly as "How so?" The point of the question, presumably, is to get the girl to identify the parts of the ink blot that would correspond to a frog's head, body, and legs.

Answer (score 2):

To me the "from where" part would imply "from what perspective" or in other words - "from what angle/distance".  This is a lot different than "What part of the image looks like a frog to you?"

I could see her wording leading to confusion depending on the interpretation of the phrase.

I'm sure it felt natural to say that, or she would've used another phrase, but it is the least ambiguous? I don't think so.

Comment: It might even be metaphorical – Where are you coming from?

Comment: So @Edwin Ashworth what do you think will be used? The sentence with :from" or  without "from"?

Comment: I wouldn't use either. To clarify, if I was asking about a particular direction of viewing, I'd say 'Show me where to look from to see that it looks something like a frog' whereas if I thought that the girl's statement was more subjectively based I'd say 'I'm sorry, I can't see a frog there. What makes you say so?'